# How did Loki survive at the end of Thor?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, thor

At the end of *Thor*, we see Thor holding onto Odin and Loki holding onto Thor. Loki lets go and falls into the wormhole.

We know he survived because he's the main villain in the Avengers.

How did he survive falling into wormhole? If he was just teleported and not killed, would he not have ended up in Jotunheim which was being destroyed?

Comment: Similar question in scifi too http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/lokis-return-in-the-avengers-movie/23937#23937

Comment: I would say Odin used his powers on Loki so he would survive

Comment: @olivianovak Have you any reasoning behind your comment?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is never said explicitly how exactly he survived, but in *The Avengers* it is hinted that he was saved by the  Chitauri and their leader. A mysterious character by the name "The Other" tells Loki:

> The Other: You question us? You question HIM? He, who put the scepter in your hand, who gave you ancient knowledge and new purpose when you were cast out, defeated?

(source: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/quotes?qt=qt1698722))

Answer (score 2):

Going into space wouldn't necessarily kill him, he is a frost giant/ extraterrestrial being. Peter Quill survives it with just a mask and with Loki knowledge of magic, he would know how to survive. He did sneak to the ice planet without Heimdal seeing him. In Thor Ragnarok his is forced out of the biofrost and safely arrives on Scart. He is capable of transporting outside of the biofrost and  to different dimensions in ways other can't.

Answer (score -1):

He created the illusion of him falling just as he created the illusion of him dying in "Thor: The Dark World".

Comment: Any evidence to support this claim?

Answer (score -1):

He fell into Jotunheim as the gateway closed, but the whole reason the Bifrost was destroyed was so that Jotunheim wouldn't get destroyed. He would have survived, and they were mourning because since the Bifrost was destroyed, they thought he was lost forever.

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, and/or adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found. I hope you enjoy participating.

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this question is: **He didn't survive the fall**. It is already stated in Avengers: Infinity War what happened to him after the events of Thor (2011).

Thanos stated after he choked Loki to death that "*No resurrections this time.*". We can presume that Loki died from the fall and then found by Thanos or his minions then resurrected him given the accounts as an Asgardian and Odin's son (though adopted) and possibly, a skillful ally.

Comment: I don't think Thanos meant *literal* resurrections. I think he was simply referring to the fact that we've seen Loki "die" several times before, and every time has been a trick of some kind. In Infinity War, Thanos was making it very clear that this was not a trick anymore, the real Loki was the one being killed.

Comment: @MageXy I get your point. But with Thanos' point of view, I don't think he knows everything that is happenning in the MCU. Also, Thanos is not a kind of man who talks figuratively. Given the conversation between Gamora and him in the Santuary II, He is direct and precise.  All he is is what experience has given to him.

Answer (score -6):

Gods can only be killed by another god, or banished, otherwise Loki is also able to contort himself and control the elements as well, so the worm hole wouldn't have killed him but just made it difficult to come back – Odin and Thor are upset because they can only travel to realms using the rainbow bridge; Loki basically got lost in the heavens and the wormhole made it a one-way trip.

Comment: What particular aspect of him being a god made him survive?

Comment: Perhaps you should add that into your answer.

Comment: Just my opinion lol

Comment: When did it got established this way?

Comment: This has been confirmed to be wrong. In *Infinity War*, Loki is killed by Thanos, who is not a god.